# Get the values of another method of an object

Tags: jquery

I am trying to learn oops concept, below i want to calculate something.

```
(function(){
var rectangle= {
    specs: function(length, width){
        length= length;
        width= width;
        this.calculate();
    },

    calculate: function(){
        //How can i refer here the diameter and height passed in the specs method above
         console.log(length * width)
    }
};
rectangle.specs(10, 20);
})();
```

thanks

Comment: You can use `this` keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it one of two ways, depending on how accessible you want the variables to be after calling the specs method.

The first way, if you want the variables to only be contained inside of the methods you've listed, is to simply pass the arguments to the second method you are calling. Edits are surrounded by **:

```
(function(){
var rectangle= {
    specs: function(length, width){
        length= length;
        width= width;
        this.calculate(**length, width**);
    },

    calculate: function(**length, width**){
        //How can i refer here the diameter and height passed in the specs method above
         console.log(length * width)
    }
};
rectangle.specs(10, 20);
})();
```

The second way makes the variables assigned to the object, and can therefore be accessed outside the object using rectangle.length or rectangle.width, or internally using the "this" keyword. Edits are surrounded by **:

```
(function(){
var rectangle= {
    specs: function(length, width){
        **this.length** = length;
        **this.width** = width;
        this.calculate();
    },

    calculate: function(){
        //How can i refer here the diameter and height passed in the specs method above
         console.log(**this.length * this.width**)
    }
};
rectangle.specs(10, 20);
})();
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks B. Aikey